# long-running data-science background jobs in firebase

Tags: firebase

I have a mobile app that will need to calculate k-means clusters from the entire users data set hourly - and then update each user's favorites list in real-time, how would I run this long-running job in firebase?

I can use a queue service like ironMQ and run the background job elsewhere on something like mortar or amazon lambda - but I'd prefer to keep it all in the same place as I'd have to shuttle the entire user data set around.

Does firebase support use cases like this?

Comment: I noticed you're asking the same question about parse.com (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28395020/), isn't this akin to asking for a technology recommendation?

Comment: I don't actually want a parse vs firebase discussion.  I figured people might not be familiar with the ins/outs of both services so I wanted to see how they would be implemented in both and I could do the evaluation myself to compare the two.

Comment: I think if you narrow the question to how you can create this long-running job in Firebase, and add some specific details about the use case, you can probably get this question answered. As it stands, it's juts a recommendation for a service. The answer to how to create the long-running job "in firebase" is to use a node.js service, Big Query, or other to perform the updates and push data into Firebase. There are no stored procedures or procedural code that run internally to Firebase.

Comment: Hi Kato, I think you just answered the question - "there are no stored procedures or procedural code that run internally to Firebase" ..  I think there should be enough detail in the question about the job - it's specifically a k-means clustering algorithm that will run across the users collection in firebase.  As an alternative, the use case could even be as simple as I need to calculate total likes for every user on an hourly basis.