# running data science clustering job with a parse.com background job

Tags: parse-platform

So I have a mobile app that wants to use parse for login, user data, content, etc... but I also need to run an hourly k-means clustering job on my entire user data set. I was looking at Parse jobs as a possible solution.  My question is since the clustering algorithms will probably take up a lot of memory - since they will need to load all the users into memory - will it be possible or useful to use parse for this, or to run map reduce jobs with the the background jobs.... or is this really beyond the means of parse and I should look at setting up my own backend instead of using a backend-as-a-service.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Parse offers background jobs https://parse.com/docs/cloud_code_guide#jobs

As long as the job completes within 15 minutes, it is fine.

However, there is an open bug on Parse that hasn't been fixed over the last 1.5 months. We believe that this is actually a memory issue (and if that's the case you might run into it, as well). Here's the bug ID: https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/1586656868273252/